# Projection matrices: What should depth map to?

Tags: opengl, graphics, vulkan

I'm running into contradictions while attempting to build a projection matrix for Vulkan, and have yet to find an explanation for how the projection matrix should map Z from input vector to the output. Mapping x and y is straightforward. My understanding is that OpenGL Projection matrices should map the near frustum plane to -1, and far to +1. Vulkan to 0 and +1 respectively. The mapping should be logarithmic, allowing greater precision in the near field.

The examples below use near (n) = 1, far (f) = 100.
Here's a plot of z mapping using a matrix I constructed to the Vulkan spec. It produces errors in rendering, but produces the correct result as I understand it:

`lambda z: (f / (f-n) * z - f*n/(f-n)) / z`
[image]

A plot of the most common OpenGL projection I've found online, which should map from -1 to +1:

`lambda z: ((-f+n)/(f-n)*z - 2*f*n/(f-n))/-z`
[image]

And here's one generated from a lib I use, for OpenGL (cgmath in Rust):
[image]

I'm unable to build a proper Vulkan projection matrix (Of which I've found none via Google) unless I understand what z should map to. I suspect this is due to an implicit correction done post projection matrix by the shader that actually maps to the ranges I listed, but if so, I don't know what range to feed into it via the proj mat.

Comment: Did You try projection matrix from the "Vulkan Cookbook"? It's available here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Library/Source%20Files/10%20Helper%20Recipes/04%20Preparing%20a%20perspective%20projection%20matrix.cpp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The mapping should be logarithmic, allowing greater precision in the near field.

Actually, if you don't do any tricks, the mapping will be *hyperbolic*, not logarithmic. The key point about the hyperbolic mapping is that you can actually interpolate it linear in screen space (which is a very nice property when you want to do some Z buffer optimizations like Hierarchical Z).

> A plot of the most common OpenGL projection I've found online, which should map from -1 to +1:
>
> ```
> lambda z: ((-f+n)/(f-n)*z - 2*f*n/(f-n))/-z
> ```

Nope. You have a sign error in the first term, it should be

```
(-(f+n)/(f-n)*z - 2*f*n/(f-n))/-z
```

Hence, your plot is just wrong. With the corrected formula, you would get a plot similiar to your `cgmath` rust library.

But the important bit is something else: *you are plotting the wrong thing*!
Note the `-z` on denominator in that formula? Classic GL convention has always been to use a *right handed* eye space, but *left handed* window space. As a result, a classic GL projection matrix projects along `-z` direction. The parameters `n` and `f` are still given as distances along the viewing direction, though. This means, that the actual clip planes will be at `z_eye = -n` and `z_eye=-f` in eye space. What you plotted in your graph is the range *behind* the camera, and you will see the second branch of the hyperbole, the one which is usually clipped ayway, and which will map to outside of the `[-1,1]` interval.

If you plot the mapping for n=5 and f=100, you would get:
[image: plot of hyperbolic Z function]

Note that OpenGL's project into `-z` direction is pure convention, it is not enforced by anything, so you can use `+z` projection matrix as well.

> I'm unable to build a proper Vulkan projection matrix (Of which I've found none via Google) unless I understand what z should map to.
>   Here's a plot of z mapping using a matrix I constructed to the Vulkan spec. It produces errors in rendering, but produces the correct result as I understand it:
>
> ```
> lambda z: (f / (f-n) * z - f*n/(f-n)) / z
> ```

Not sure what errors you're seeing with this, but the mapping is correct if you

1. assume vulkan's default [0,1] z clip conventions, and
2. want a projection direction along `+z` in eye space.

Btw. vulkans `[0,1]` clip convention also makes it possible to better use the precisions when using a floating point depth attachment: By reversing the mapping so that the near plane is mapped to 1, and the far plane mapped to 0, you can improve precision considerably. Have a look at [this nvidia devblog article](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized) for more details.

Comment: I with I could upvote this more than once. Very well written! You've beaten me to it, and got it done in a much more concise and clear way.